# ReflectionTypeLoadException with null LoaderExceptions and null InnerException

Tags: c#, exception, reflection

What is the likely cause of a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` that has both a `null` `LoaderExceptions` property and a `null` `InnerException` property?

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.reflectiontypeloadexception%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) reads as if `LoaderExceptions` will always contain exceptions detailing the specific types that could not be loaded, but this is clearly not always true.  So what situations would cause the exception to be thrown in this state?

*There are a number of questions on SO about the `ReflectionTypeLoadException`.  However, none of them address this specific scenario.*

Comment: This is kind of a roundabout way of getting at your actual problem. You're clearly trying to use reflection to load a type and it's dying miserably and in a way that is making it difficult for you to debug. So, why don't you just give us the smallest and simplest code that reproduces the problem and then we can noodle on it from there?

Comment: Agreed, but this is happening on a remote client site.  I have no access to the box and am unable to reproduce the issue locally.